# Adding a custom filter for active admin children count not showing in search result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models, user and reviews, and I would like to filter the associations created_at.

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
end
```

**models/reviews.rb**

```
class Reviews < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  scope :by_duration, -> (from, to) { where(created_at: from.to_date.beginning_of_day..to.to_date.end_of_day) if from.present? && to.present? }
end
```

By default, the number of reviews column shows all the reviews count. But admin can also filter the creation of reviews.

**admin/users.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  config.sort_order = "name_asc"
  config.per_page = 10

  filter :name

  filter :reviews_datetime, as: :date_range, label: "Reviews Date Range"

  index title: 'User and reviews count', downloadable_links: [:csv] do 
    column :name
    
    column ('Number of Reviews') do |item| 
      if params['q'] && params['q']['filter_reviews_gteq_datetime'].present? && params['q']['filter_reviews_lteq_datetime'].present?

        item.reviews.by_duration(params['q']['filter_reviews_gteq_datetime'], params['q']['filter_reviews_lteq_datetime']).count

      else
        item.reviews.count
      end
    end     

  end
  
end
```

The filter result should shows the date range, but currently it's not showing.

[image: The filter result should shows the date range]